# Aggregated JSONB result in update query

Tags: postgresql, update, json

### Introduction

I created a toy example to extract the problem into a smaller part. 
Here is the schema definition with two tables users and events, users can have multiple events:

```
create table users (
    id int, name text, history jsonb
);
insert into users(id, name) values (1, 'Mike'), (2, 'Jake'), (3, 'Toots');


create table events (
    id serial, user_id int, external_id int, type text, timestamp timestamp
);

# Generate test data
insert into events (external_id, user_id, type, timestamp) 
    select x % 5 + 1, x % 3 + 1, 'random', NOW() - '1 day'::interval * (random()::int * 100) from generate_series(1, 3000000) as x;
```

With the actual data, the users table would be lower volume table less than ~1M records and events table quite high ~25M records.

### Problem

Update users table history column which would be an aggregated result of the events table as jsonb. The events should be grouped together by external_id, user_id based on that the object with min(timestamp) and max(timestamp) would be great.

History example: 
`history: [{start: '2018-12-12', end: '2018-12-20', external_id: 1}, {start: '2018-11-12', end: '2018-11-20', external_id: 2}]`

My example, the grouping part seems to be **not correct** as an only single object is returned in the subquery. Also by performance wise, this is not the best solution.

```
 update users
    set history = e.history
    from (
        select 
            user_id,
            json_build_array(
                json_build_object(
                  'start', MIN(timestamp),
                  'end', MAX(timestamp),
                  'external_id', external_id,
                  'is_fetched', true
                )::jsonb) history
        from events 
        group by external_id, user_id
    ) e 
    where users.id = e.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the solution you're looking for, but IMHO you should get the aggregated values and then build the array.

```
WITH t AS 
(
  SELECT
      user_id,
      jsonb_build_object('start', MIN(timestamp), 
                         'end', MAX(timestamp),
                         'external_id', external_id,
                         'is_fetched', true) ev
  FROM 
      events
  GROUP BY
      user_id,
      external_id
), t2 AS
(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    jsonb_agg(ev) history
  FROM
    t
  GROUP BY
    user_id
)
UPDATE users AS usr
SET    history = t2.history
FROM   t2
WHERE  usr.id = t2.user_id;
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | history                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
> -: | :---- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | Mike  | [{"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 1}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 5}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 3}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 4}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 2}]
>  2 | Jake  | [{"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 3}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 2}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 4}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 1}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 5}]
>  3 | Toots | [{"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 3}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 1}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 4}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 2}, {"end": "2019-01-26T17:14:37.349739", "start": "2018-10-18T17:14:37.349739", "is_fetched": true, "external_id": 5}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e8c3520207d0fd6477e176f5f15a1eb4)*

Comment: Ty for correcting yes the extra step was missing :y: